# Generalized geometric series value

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Why the value of the following summation:

$$1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\bigg(1- \frac{76}{i}\bigg)^k= \frac{i}{76}$$

is $\frac{i}{76}$? $\quad i$ is a positive constant.

Comment: Sum $S_{n}$ of $n$ terms of a geometric series is $S_{n}=\frac{a(r^{n}-1)}{r-1}$. Here $a=(1-\frac{76}{i})$, $r=(1-\frac{76}{i})$ and $n=n$

Comment: It is not. For instance, take $i=152$ and $k=2$: $\frac12+\frac14+1\neq2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-\frac{76}{i})^{k}$$

is geometric series, where $q=1-\frac{76}{i}$ so:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-\frac{76}{i})^{k}=-\frac{(1-\frac{76}{i})^{n+1}-(1-\frac{76}{i})}{1-(1-\frac{76}{i})}=-\frac{i}{76}\left((1-\frac{76}{i})^{n+1}-(1-\frac{76}{i})\right)=\\=-\frac{i}{76}\left((1-\frac{76}{i})^{n+1}\right)+\frac{i}{76}-1$$

So when $\left|1-\frac{76}{i}\right|<1$ and $n \to \infty$ we have:

$$-\frac{i}{76}\left((1-\frac{76}{i})^{n+1}\right)+\frac{i}{76}-1 \to \frac{i}{76}-1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1- x)^k = (1-x)\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1- x)^k \right] = (1-x)\frac{1- (1-x)^n}{1-(1-x)}$$

When $|1-x|<1$ and $n$ goes to infinity we get

$$ \frac{1-x}{x} = \frac{1}{x}-1.$$